# Plot intersection of row and colum values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel like there is a simple solution to this that I am overlooking?
I have column headers with unique values and a single column (A) with rows of data. I am looking for a way to mark the cell in the corresponding column for the value found in the column A of the row. See screenshot for example. I don't care what it is marked with (X in screenshot example). A solution that would easily executable against 30+ columns and thousands of rows would be preferable.
[image]

Comment: I use iferror() with match() and find() but only for up to 30 cells - for the number you describe then vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following in `B2`: `=IF(B$1=$A2,"X","")`
Drag this to the right and down.
But using vba would be better.